# Populate textbox with JSON object from c# LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, linq

I'm trying to populate two textboxes with data from a .cs page that returns a JSON object but the textboxes don't populate. It doesn't show an error and on firebug I see the object.
Here's the response:

> {"d":"[{\"ProjectContactFirstName\":\"asdfa\",\"ProjectContactLastName\":\"adsf\"}]"}

Here's the AJAX code and WebMethod that does the query.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "view-requests.aspx/getProjectByID",   // Current Page, Method
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), // parameter map as JSON
    type: "POST", // data has to be POSTed
    contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content    
    dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)
    timeout: 10000,    // AJAX timeout
    success: function (result) {
        //alert(result);
        $("#txtContactFirstEdit").val(result.ProjectContactFirstName); <-- How do I populate from JSON?
        $("#txtContactLastEdit").val(result.ProjectContactLastName); <-- How do I populate from JSON?
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Here's the WebMethod that returns the JSO for the success to populate textbox. Just not sure how to give it to the AJAX.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getProjectByID(int id)
{
    using (dbPSREntities4 myEntities = new dbPSREntities4())
    {
        var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id);
        var columns = thisProject.Select(x => new { x.ProjectContactFirstName, x.ProjectContactLastName }).ToList();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(columns);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is and what the question is?

Comment: Sorry... I clarified the question above. :)

Comment: You are double-serializing your result 1) `serializer.Serialize(columns);` 2) `WebService framework` for your string. Either return your object directly in webmethod(without using *JavaScriptSerializer*) or use Json.parse in your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is returning a JSON array wrapped in an object, thus your code should look more like this:

```
    success: function (result) {
        //alert(result);
        $("#txtContactFirstEdit").val(result.d[0].ProjectContactFirstName); <-- How do I populate from JSON?
        $("#txtContactLastEdit").val(result.d[0].ProjectContactLastName); <-- How do I populate from JSON?
    }
```